# Request loses "error" field after adding "params" into @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, error-handling

in order to handle a few situations with the same resource path, eg:

/path/to/resource?param1=a

/path/to/resource?param2=a

I introduced into @RequestMapping params. Looks like this now:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = PM_DATA_ROUTE, params = {"system", "className", "source", "fromTimestampInNanos", 
        "toTimestampInNanos"})
public List<PmDataInformationWrapper> getPmData(
        @Valid TimestampRangePmDataRequestParameter timestampRangePmDataRequestParameter) {
    LOGGER.info(REQUEST_RECEPTION_LOG, timestampRangePmDataRequestParameter);
    return pmDataManagerAdapter.getPmData(timestampRangePmDataRequestParameter);
}

@Override
@RequestMapping(value = PM_DATA_ROUTE, params = {"system", "className", "source", "fromTimestampInNanos", 
        "durationInNanos"})
public List<PmDataInformationWrapper> getPmData(
        @Valid TimestampDurationPmDataRequestParameter timestampDurationPmDataRequestParameter) {
    LOGGER.info(REQUEST_RECEPTION_LOG, timestampDurationPmDataRequestParameter);
    return pmDataManagerAdapter.getPmData(timestampDurationPmDataRequestParameter);
}
```

these values like system, className, etc - are names of fields encapsulated into object request parameters that I'm expecting in controller method signature.

This works fine, besides one little issue. If I don't put this "params" explicitly into @RequestParam and then miss something from client side - the error response is meaningful and looks like this:

> "errors": [
>       "'timestampInNanos' parameter cannot be omitted!"
>     ],

The message itself comes from validation. Doesn't matter.

After I added this params into @RequestMapping, the error response of the same situation looks like this:

> "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException",
>     "errors": []

No even single word about missing params, because in this case it does not even step into the controller method (which is actually reasonable).

Usually I was looking for the errors in ServletRequestAttributes of request, which contains errorAttributes.

Now I have no idea what to do about.

Does anyone have some ideas how to get some more meaningful message about missing params in this particular case?

I'm aware that if we don't step into the desired method, and then just jump into default error handling controller - it might be difficult to say anything, but on the other hand - APIs like this are not rare, so there is probably some good practice how to handle such a situation...

Thanks in advance!